# How to pass an array as a command line argument in Microsoft visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command, arguments

I am using visual studio and adding arguments here to debug, is there a way that I can input an array like -write-key 6 {an array}

[image]

[image]

basically I have a method writekey that takes an array parameter, now in visual studio Project->properties-> Debug-> start options

I am trying to invoke this method and pass an array in.
i could do pass in other parameter types like 
  -writekey 1

-writekey string

but I cant do - writekey {1,2,3}

{1,2,3} as an array. is there any way to do it? I tried [1,2,3] 1,2,3 (1,2,3) none of them works.

Comment: Post your code into the website, links die.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no immediate way to achieve this result.
You could simply put a string like "1,2,3,4" and then simply using a one-liner like this:

```
var bytes = Args[0].Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll(Convert.ToByte);
```

Ofc assuming the param is in position 0 in args.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score -1):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/how-to-display-command-line-arguments) suggests you can pass an array of space-separated strings to Visual Studio which worked for me.